# Relative importance different model diagnostics in LMM/GLMM

Tags: mixed-model, residuals, glmm, misspecification

I may be over thinking things but I have been stuck on this issue for the last few days. I am currently modelling data with a large number of clusters but cluster size is limited to 2, with a skewed continuous outcome. My parameters of interest are the ICC and one or two of the fixed effects coefficients - that are record (not cluster) specific. I am keen to generate interpretable coefficients and hence I have tried the following with the issues as noted- see plots below.

I'm working in R (lme4).

MODEL 1) LMM - on original scale i.e. with gaussian family and identity link. Issues: skew in residuals, shapiro-wilk (SW( test of residuals p = 0.005., Levene Test not significant

[image: Model 1]

MODEL 2) LMM - square root transformed response variable (which approximates fairly well to a gaussian distribution). Residuals look better but there is still a trend in my Fitted Vs Residual plot. SW p = 0.5148. Also, loss of interpretability...

[image: MODEL 2]

3) GLMM - original response variable but with family = gaussian and link = power (0.5). I can then get the effects  I need on the original scale for my coefficients of interest (using R:margins pkg). However, the ICC seems inappropriately larger (this was noted in the [Nakagawa paper 2017](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/pmid/28904005/)) - I am not aware of any other packages that support the power link function that I can cross reference with. Additionally, the residual Vs fitted is now 'random' but I seem to have generated heteroscedasticity through this process and SW is significant p = 0.0063

[image: MODEL 3]

DHARMa residuals seem to suggest Model 2 over Model 3 - I am partial to Model 3 for interpretability but would not want to significantly violate modelling assumptions.

MODEL 1
[image: Residuals Model 1]

MODEL 2
[image: Residuals Model 2]

MODEL 3
[image: Residuals Model 3]

I would like to know:

1) Is there a heirarchy of diagnostic testing of residuals I should adhere to i.e. linearity >> homoscedasticity >> normality?

2) Which method would lead to less bias in A) ICC measurement and B) Fixed Coefficient of interest

3) I value interpretable coefficients if at all possible (i.e. on the original scale but the ICC measurements I get from MODEL3 are very different from MODEL 1 and 2 - which mirror each other fairly well.